# Laravel 5.4 - Where to change login procedure

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Using the command `php artisan make:auth` I 'created' the default authentication scaffolding.

My application, however, needs rights management. I added a column via the migrations for the rights (small int).

Now, when a user logs in, I want to check the rights the user has and redirect according to the rights.

Where is the actual redirect located (in which PHP file)? So that I can edit this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the `LoginController` and the `RegistrationController`. They are based on some traits (with a lot of protected methods you can adapt)